# modify bsxfun for checking significant values

Tags: matlab

I had this problem...i.e. to find significant values between groups in my Data array.
My solution was:

```
Data = [1.8,1.4, 1.5;
60, 70, 80;
20, 40, 5];

Error = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4;
20, 30, 10;
10,5,2];

    k = 1; 

for i = 1: size(Data,1)

    if ((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2)))

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i ,1, 2];

      k = k+1;
    end

    if ((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,3)+Error(i,3)))

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i , 1, 3];

      k = k+1;
    end

    if ((Data(i,2)-Error(i,2)) > (Data(i,3)+Error(i,3)))

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i , 2, 3];

      k = k+1;
    end

end

selectedpar = [1    1   2
3   1   3
3   2   3]
```

Thanks to an user I came to this other general solution (removed series of if conditions)

```
DM = Data-Error;
DP = Data+Error;
selectedpar = [];
for k=1:size(Data,1)
   [I,J]=find(tril(bsxfun(@gt, DM(k,:), DP(k,:).')));
   selectedpar = [selectedpar ; k+zeros(size(I)), J, I];  %#ok<AGROW>
end
```

Now I would like to add another condition: in particular instead of the single if I would like to check for

```
if ((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2)) || (Data(i,1)+Error(i,1)) < (Data(i,2)-Error(i,2))) etc...
```

so my ugly solution would be

```
    k = 1; 

for i = 1: size(Data,1)

    if ((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2)) || (Data(i,1)+Error(i,1)) < (Data(i,2)-Error(i,2)) )

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i ,1, 2];

      k = k+1;
    end

    if ((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,3)+Error(i,3)) || (Data(i,1)+Error(i,1)) < (Data(i,3)-Error(i,3)))

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i , 1, 3];

      k = k+1;
    end

    if ((Data(i,2)-Error(i,2)) > (Data(i,3)+Error(i,3)) || (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2)) < (Data(i,3)-Error(i,3)))

      selectedpar(k,1:3) = [i , 2, 3];

      k = k+1;
    end

end

selectedpar = [1    1   2
3   1   2
3   1   3
3   2   3]
```

(correct solution)

How can I modify the bsxfun to add the second part of the new if condition (the one after the OR)

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about changing tril in triu to compute also the other if

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment to your previous question: simply add another `bsxfun` line interchanging `DM` and `DP`, and changing `@gt` to `@lt`; and then collect results with another `selectedpar = ...` line:

```
DM = Data-Error;
DP = Data+Error;
selectedpar = [];
for k=1:size(Data,1)
   [I,J]=find(tril(bsxfun(@gt, DM(k,:), DP(k,:).')));
   selectedpar = [selectedpar ; k+zeros(size(I)), J, I];  %#ok<AGROW>
   [I,J]=find(tril(bsxfun(@lt, DP(k,:), DM(k,:).'))); %%%NEW LINE
   selectedpar = [selectedpar ; k+zeros(size(I)), J, I];  %#ok<AGROW> %%%NEW LINE
end
```